# Why HttpResponseMessage is not the same when I call Method throught webapi or directly

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, webapi

I have an issue that I don't understand.
I try to call a External WebApi through my own WebApi (CustomApi) in .Net 6.

When I use Postman to call External Api I get Reponse 404 with json message like :

[response from external api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPqKW.png)

When I call my own api I get Response 200 with json like:

[response throught my own api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfndv.png)

My methode is:

```
    [HttpGet("GetDocument")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetDocument()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri(url),
            Headers =
            {
                { "Authorization", "Bearer " + _bearer },
            }
        };

        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
        {
            return response;
        }
    }
```

It seems the same result but where response was serialized, and I would like return the exact response of the external API.
Have someone know the reason of this behaviour?

Comment: You are sending back the whole response object, what you want is the content (and the status code).

Answer (score 0):

First change your return type to `Task<IActionResult>` and the method body to:

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    RequestUri = new Uri(url),
    Headers =
    {
        { "Authorization", "Bearer " + _bearer },
    }
};

using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
{
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
    {
        return new ObjectResult(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClassIfResponseIsOk>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())) 
        {
           StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode,  
        }
    }
    
    return new ObjectResult(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClassIfSomeErrorOccurred>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())) 
    {
       StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode,  
    }   
}
```